# SQL Express: Backup job to auto increment date/time?

Tags: sql, backup

Trying to create a backup job to auto increment the backup file name on this script but getting this on syntax. 
Idea is to setup a job that runs every x amount of hours and take a backup of the DB on the same location. Filename has to be incremented or the job will fail (and yes I've tried doing this from the msdn suggested way but somehow my batch file doesn't want to work.

```
USE TESTDB;
GO
declare @Date DATE = GetDate()
BACKUP DATABASE TESTDB
TO DISK = 'D:\Test\TESTDB.Bak' 
   WITH FORMAT,
      MEDIANAME = 'TESTDB',
      NAME = 'TESTDB'&@Date&'.BAK';
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Date use varchar variable for name

```
declare @Date as varchar(20)
set @Date =   CAST( getdate() AS DATE);
declare @Name varchar(40) = 'Backup to TESTDB at'+@Date+'.BAK'
BACKUP DATABASE 'TESTDB'TO DISK = 'D:\TEST\TESTDB.Bak' 
 -- use NOFORMAT for Add Backup
  WITH NOFORMAT,
  MEDIANAME = 'TESTDB',
  NAME =@name;
go
```

so you can change Disk name for séparate Backup

```
declare @Date as varchar(20)
set @Date =   CAST( getdate() AS DATE);
declare @disk varchar(100) = 'D:\TEST\TESTDB'+@Date+'.BAK'
declare @Name varchar(40) = 'Backup to TESTDB at'+@Date+'.BAK'
BACKUP DATABASE 'TESTDB'TO DISK = @disk
 -- use FORMAT for erase Backup
  WITH NOFORMAT,
  MEDIANAME = 'TESTDB',
  NAME =@name;
go
```

Comment: The data types varchar and date are incompatible in the '&' operator.